# Convert standard Datetime format in given format using c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert a Datetime in c# into a specific format as 2002-09-24+06:00.

I want the result in a Datetime variable and not string since I need to pass that to a SOAP call that is expecting a Datetime in that format.

How can I get this result?

Comment: A `DateTime` has no _format_ but just a value, so this is clearly a `string`: `2002-09-24+06:00`.

Comment: HI Tim . This is datetime in UTC with offset (+6:00) against the local time

Comment: @Mohitsikri - [`DateTime`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,128): "The data is stored as an unsigned 64-bit integeter" - bits 1-62 are the number of 100 nanosecond ticks that have happened since 1/1/0001 12:00am. The other 2 bits store what kind of datetime it is (Utc or Local). There *is* no format. It doesn't remember *how* it was created, or what *string* was used to create it.

Comment: You may want to take a look on `DateTimeOffset`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` object doesn't have a format and just stores the date as a value. And if your Webservice expect a special format, I'm shure it wants a `string`.

You can get this special formatted string like this:

```
String.Format("{YOUR_FORMAT}", YOUR_DATETIME_OBJECT);
```

If your SOAP need the type `xs:dateTime` try it with the following formatting as a `string`:

```
YOUR_DATETIME_OBJECT.ToString("o")
```

This will give you the format: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`

Comment: Hi Claudio ,

Thanks for the response . I wish it was expecting a  string but it dosent and expects a Datetime which is in standard with the w3

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp

Comment: @Mohitsikri I updated my answer. Please give it a try.

Comment: Sorry dont know how that will give me the desired result as in get the value in that format into a Datetime variable

Comment: @Mohitsikri As I already said. The DateTime object doesn't have a format. Have you already tried to forget about the Date format and just hand over your DateTime object? The serialization of the .NET-framework should do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the DateTime object around, but format it accordingly using the `DateTime.ToString()` method:

MSDN: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

**C# code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DateTime dd;
    String dd_format = "yyyy-MM-dd+HH:mm";

    dd = new DateTime(2002, 9, 24, 6, 0, 0);
    Response.Write(dd.ToString(dd_format) + "<BR />");

    dd = new DateTime(2002, 9, 24, 13, 0, 0);
    Response.Write(dd.ToString(dd_format) + "<BR />");
}
```

**Output**

`2002-09-24+06:00`

`2002-09-24+13:00`